# How to create a vertex on a parallel edge?

Tags: modeling

I'm having this structure:

[image]

I would like to create a vertex where the arrow points to. This is the opposite of an existing vertex on the right edge, so just shifted a bit along y to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the edge (as you did in the screenshot), press <kbd>RMB</kbd> > *Subdivide*. Hit <kbd>1</kbd> to enter *Vertex Edit Mode*. Select the new vertex, double-tap <kbd>G</kbd> to move the vertex along the edge with *Vertex Slide*.

Comment: Thanks. That was helpful.